# Text wrapped in polygon shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Created a polygon shape using CSS. But, The inner content of the `polygon` layout does not follow the polygon shape. It is hidden by the shape clipping.

Need to **wrap the text in the polygon**.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
.polygon1,
.polygon2 {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 90% 20%, 100% 60%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 60%, 10% 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 90% 20%, 100% 60%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 60%, 10% 20%);
  text-align: center;
}
.polygon1 {
  padding: 10px;
}
.polygon2 {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="polygon1">
  <div class="flex">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="polygon2">
  <div class="flex">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software.
  </div>
</div>
```

**Tried:**

- Added `padding` to the `polygon`. But, Padding `measurement` is depends on `polygon` dimensions. So, Not found exact measurement.

**Screenshot:**
[image: Text wrapped in polygon]

**Codepen:** [Goto Edit CodePen](http://codepen.io/maheshwaghmare/pen/ojKLaO)

Comment: This will help: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/

Answer (score 3):

> **WARNING :** *The shape-outside property should not be used in live projects<sup>1</sup>. This answer is here just to show how the desired output can
>   be achieved with this property.*

The shape you refered to can be achieved with the [shape-outside property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside). You can make two shapes that follow your clip-path shape. They will **wrap the text inside the polygon**. Here is an example:

```css
div {
  width: 250px; height: 250px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 90% 20%, 100% 60%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 60%, 10% 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 90% 20%, 100% 60%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 60%, 10% 20%);
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span:after,span:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50%; height: 100%;
  -webkit-shape-margin: 10px;
  shape-margin: 10px;
}
span:before {
  float: left;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 20% 20%, 0% 60%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 0%);
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 20% 20%, 0% 60%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 0%);
}
span:after {
  float: right;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 80% 20%, 100% 60%, 50% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 80% 20%, 100% 60%, 50% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software.
</div>
```

For browser support of the shape-outside property, you can check [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside).

<sup>1</sup><sub>The [CSS Shapes Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/) actualy (feb 2016) has the status of "Candidate Recommendation". As this means it is a work in progress, it may change at any moment and therefore should not be used other than for testing.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS shapes for this, but they are [not broadly supported right now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes). [Here's a great tutorial](http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101) to get started with them.

I'd use it and would try to use padding as a kind of okayish fallback. This would be a great case for using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) as a feature detector to only apply the padding if the used browser cannot render CSS shapes.